# Не понимаю в чем проблема AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

С input'ов пытаюсь отправить данные в MYSQL. Взял пример с книги "PHP7 в подлиннике", до внесения изменений :) , а именно добавил занесение номера телефона, все работало. Вроде все точно так же дописал как по примеру, но теперь вообще не работает.

**И так, я понял что я лютый программист, который не умеет ставить комментарии к коду, все было абсолютно рабочим, мне 2 дня жизни убил комментарий к коду.
Всем спасибо, все свободны, пойду плакать.**

```
<?php
 // Устанавливаем соединение с базой данных
 require_once("connect.php");
 try {
 // 1. Проверяем, переданы ли POST-параметры;
 // если ответ положительный, помещаем новое
 // сообщение в базу данных
 if(!empty($_POST))
 {
 $error = [];
 if(empty($_POST['nickname'])) {
 $error[] = "Отсутствует автор";
 }

  // phone
  if(empty($_POST['phone'])) {
  $error[] = "Отсутствует номер телефона";
  }
  //

 if(empty($_POST['content'])) {
 $error[] = "Отсутствует сообщение";
 }


 // Если нет ошибок, помещаем сообщение
 // в базу данных
 if(empty($error))
 {
 $query = "INSERT INTO
 comments
 VALUES (
 NULL,
 :nickname,
 :phone, --phone
 :content,
 NOW(),
 1)";
 $usr = $pdo->prepare($query);
 $usr->execute([
 'nickname' => $_POST['nickname'],
 'phone' => $_POST['phone'], //phone
 'content' => $_POST['content']
 ]);
 }
 }
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
 echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: " . $e->getMessage();
 }
```

```js
< script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" > < /script> <
  script type = "text/javascript" >
  // Назначить обработчики события click
  // после загрузки документа
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit-id").on("click", function() {
      // Проверяем корректность заполнения полей
      if ($.trim($("#nickname").val()) === "") {
        alert('Пожалуйста, заполните поле "Автор"');
        return false;
      }
      // phone
      if ($.trim($("#phone").val()) === "") {
        alert('Пожалуйста, заполните поле "Телефон"');
        return false;
      }
      // phone
      if ($.trim($("#content").val()) === "") {
        alert('Пожалуйста, заполните поле "Сообщение"');
        return false;
      }




      // Блокируем кнопку отправки
      $("#submit-id").prop("disabled", true);
      // AJAX-запрос
      $.ajax({
        url: "addcom.php",
        method: 'post',
        data: {
          nickname: $("#nickname").val(),
          phone: $("#phone").val(), //phone
          content: $("#content").val()
        }
      }).done(function(data) {
        // Успешное получение ответа
        $("#info").html(data);
        $("#submit-id").prop("disabled", false);
      });
    })
  }); <
/script>
```

```html
<div class="order">
  <div id='info'>
    <?php
                require_once("addcom.php");
               ?>
  </div>
  <div id='form' class="order_list">
    <p>
      <span class='ttl'>ФИО<span style="color:red;">*</span></span>
      <span class='fld'>
               <input id='nickname' type='text' placeholder="Иванов Иван Иванович" class="field" />
               </span>
    </p>

    <p>
      <span class='ttl'>Телефон<span style="color:red;">*</span></span>
      <span class='fld'>
               <input id='phone' type='text' placeholder="" class="field" />
               </span>
    </p>

    <p>
      <span class='ttl'>Сообщение<span style="color:red;">*</span></span>
      <span class='fld'>
               <!-- <textarea rows='3' id='content' type='text'></textarea> -->
               <input id='content' type='text' placeholder="Любое Ваше пожелание" class="field" />
               </span>
    </p>
    <p>
      <!-- <span class='ttl'>&nbsp;</span> -->
      <span class='fld'>
               <input id='submit-id' type='submit' value='Отправить' class="btn_field"/>
               </span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам стоит заглянуть в так называемые "Инструменты разработчика" (обычно клавиша F12) браузера, в котором во вкладке Сеть (Network) вы увидите какие данные AJAX отправляет серверной части (php) и что в ответ получает. Также стоит проверить вкладку Консоль (Console), в которой можно увидеть ошибки JS при инициализации страницы. Если вы сообщите ошибки станет сразу ясно в чем дело, так что в путь =)

Comment: Заходил, проверял, консоль пустая. А вот в network первый раз зашел, на что обратить внимание и как вообще с ней работать?